# setting textview text color with variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5, uicolor

i have a method i got colorWithHex, that lets me send a string like ffaa29 (hex) and get a UIColor. The method works. if i do

```
self._mainConsole.textColor = [self colorWithHexString: choice];
```

I can set the color. But the problem is i want to store the color.  For example if they enter an invalid color i'd want to return the current color.

When i do this it doesn't work.

```
self.foregroundColor =[self colorWithHexString: choice];
self._mainConsole.textColor = self.foregroundColor;
```

Instead it goes black which to me sounds like its going to 000000.  Now in my test ipad it works in one spot as above but not another. On a testers ipad 1 the second method doesnt work at all. What am i missing? could there be a memory issue?

Mike

Comment: How do you check if the color is invalid? What's your logic there? You want it to change color only if the color they enter is valid?

Comment: i found this colorWithHex, on the web. it just makes sure the string is 6 characters for example. that's all working fine. as i said the foreground color changes when i set from what is returned directly and not to a variable. My question is really about how to assign a color to a variable. i'm new to objective-c.  could my foregroundColor variable need memory? the function returns:

Comment: To assign the color to a variable you just need to make a `UIColor` object and store it in there. For example, you could have a `UIColor *myColor;` in your interface and then just go `myColor = [self colorWithHexString:...]` when you want to store it. (Assuming you're using ARC; if not you'd go `myColor = [[self colorWithHexString:...] retain]`)

Comment: return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                       green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                        blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                       alpha:1.0f];  do i need to do an alloc init on foregroundColor first? would it not matter since the new assignment would orphan the first memory allocation? should i alloc and init in the function before i return? should i assign memory to foregroundColor then change the setter property to copy?

Comment: if you read the post carefully that is essentialy the problem. what you suggest i see no difference from what i tried:

Comment: No need to alloc anything for the color. All you have to do is assign it. Changing the property to copy shouldn't make a difference either. Could you post some code? This doesn't really sound like a memory problem, just a logic one...

Comment: Are you using ARC? Show us how you declare your `foregroundColor` property.

Comment: thats the code. the behavior was erratic, when i do self.foregroundColor =[self colorWithHexString: choice];
self._mainConsole.textColor = self.foregroundColor; it worked on my ipad2 but not on my testers ipad1. it also failed on another device from what i gathered. that was an ipad 3 i think.

Comment: i am using auto reference counting. i have this declaration @property  (weak, nonatomic) UIColor *foregroundColor;
i do not declare the variable itself as i read the doing the property makes the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a weak property to hold your color. That means it will be replaced with `nil` as soon as there is no other strong reference to your color object. Change your property to `strong` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: I am going to try that. Sounds like it's the issue.  I just started learning ios a month ago but i have coded extensively in java, c++ and c. c more in the past and java currently as well as android.  tricky to grasp all the little quirks of memory in objective-c but i'm starting to get more of it. Just kind of learning as i code this program that i'm doing for fun.